# Creating a dictionary of dictionaries from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm reading data from a file that looks like this...

```
ID; 34556
hi; 8
lo; 16
threshold; 90
ID; 54365
hi; 0.03
lo; 8
threshold; 50
......
```

So far I have this...

```
d = {}
with open ('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        split = l.split(';')
        key = 'dictionary_key'
        if 'id' in split[0]:
           d.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault('id', split[1])
        if 'threshold' in split[0]:
            d.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault('thresh', split[1])
        if 'hi' in split[0]:
            d.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault('hi', split[1])
        if 'lo' in split[0]:
            d.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault('lo', split[1])
```

But when I do this my output is only this...

```
{'dictionary_key': {'hi': '8', 'lo': '16', 'id': '34556', 'thresh': '90'}}
```

and I can seem to create the nested dictionary for the entirety of the file.

Originally I was trying to have the id be the key and everything else fall into the nested dictionary like so...

```
{'34556': {'hi' : '8', 'lo' : '16', 'thresh' :90}}
```

but couldn't figure out how to.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating the dictionary key (or creating new dictionaries for each level), try something like this?

```
import json 

str = """
ID; 34556
hi; 8
lo; 16
threshold; 90
ID; 54365
hi; 0.03
lo; 8
threshold; 50 
"""

data = {}
id = None
for line in str.split('\n'):
    try:
        key, value = line.split('; ')
        if key == "ID":
            id = value
            data[id] = {}
        elif id is not None:
            data[id][key] = value

    except Exception as e:
        print(e, 'skipping line:', line)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

output:

```
{
    "34556": {
        "lo": "16",
        "hi": "8",
        "threshold": "90"
    },
    "54365": {
        "lo": "8",
        "hi": "0.03",
        "threshold": "50 "
    }
}
```